# How to send audio in fastes way Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm coding a telegram bot with Python using the module called python-telegram-bot.
It seems working suucesfull, but I want to improve it:
It sends to user an mp3 file, in order to do it I use the following command:

```
context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, video=open(path+tit+'.mp4', 'rb'), timeout=360)
```

But when I try to execute the command, it requires about 2/3 minutes in order to send it correctly. Do you have some tips can improve this time? Or is there a more efficient way than this? Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You snippet shows how to send a video instead of an audio file, but I guess that doesn't matter much here :D

If you send a file by uploading it, you will just have to wait until it's uploaded completely - how fast that works depends on your internet connection.
Sending files is faster, if you send them by URL or file id. The former may not be an option for you. The latter can be an option, if you need to send the same file multiple times. In that case, you can send it just once, save the resulting file_id and use that in the next calls.

In case you're stuck with uploading the file, you can still speed up your bot using multi threading, i.e. don't wait with uploading the file before processing the next update. See this [wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Performance-Optimizations).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Oh really sorry. That was my old code. The string that I actually use contains 'send_audio' instead 'send_video' :D

Comment: Anyway, the files that I try to send are uploaded once-so I need to upload new files everytime.- So I guess that using the command the only thing I can improve is my internet connection and nothing else, right?

Comment: No worries. Improve your internet connection or use multi threading as pointed out in the third paragraph ;)